# Toilet tank will not refill after flush unless water valve is closed and reopened

Tags: toilet

After flushing the toilet won't refill. However if I turn off the water supply and turn it back on the toilet will refill immediately.

What is the problem and how do I correct it?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the inside of tank?

Comment: *"How weird is that?"* -  8 on the RGB scale.

Comment: The pressure drop and rise must allow a sticky float valve to release. I'd replace the internals with an inexpensive repair kit.

Comment: @isherwood is probably right. I recently had the same problem and replaced the fill valve to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Some fill valves have a device that shuts the water off if it detects tank leakage. Sometimes these devices get sticky and the pressure has to be cycled to open the valve. I have not been able to clean one in the past and have had to replace the fill valve when this happens regulary.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests a sticky or broken fill valve. Open the tank and inspect the valve for any obvious damage. Check the fittings to the valve. Check that the float is not stuck or blocked.

Replacement valve assemblies are inexpensive and easy to install. Replacing the fill valve should fix it.